# Can I use ssl from aws instead of lets-encrypt for the address (ip) itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I want to create ssl for the application for security and try to install lets encrypt but this is only possible for the domain .

Can i install ssl for barer ip using aws services? does it make sense or just complicate?

Answer (score 0):

ACMs SSLs that are added to ELBs and CloudFront (public certificate authority) are not able to be applied to any device. If cost isn't a factor then look at [private certificate authority](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/) although I believe you'd be better off going with Lets Encrypt